# HttpURLConnection keeping cache

Tags: java, android, caching, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I am currently using this code to get data from server

```
public static String getResponse(String URL) throws IOException{

    try{
        String response_string;
        StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()));
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(strLine);
            }
            input.close();
            response_string = response.toString();
        }

        httpconn.disconnect();

        return response_string;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new IOException();
    }

}
```

But it looks like it is keeping cache, maybe not I am not sure, but if I change the data on the server and reopen the activity it's still remains the same on application. I have been using `HttpClient` before which was working good, but because it is deprecated since `API 22` I changed it to `HttpURLConnection`. So is there any way to fix this?

Comment: does ``context.getCacheDir()`` have anything in it?

Comment: No, I have never used that.

Comment: By "reopen" do you mean going to the running applications and reopen from there or do you mean closing the app and openning again?

Comment: I meant closing the activity and opening it again. But I have as well tried closing the whole application and opening it again.

Comment: I mean if you print ``context.getCacheDir()`` during execution and check that directory, does it have anything in it? I might have automatically cached the data there

Comment: Are you caching the value returned by `getResponse()` internally within the application?

Comment: @StephenG Yes it is returning a directory location `data/data/package.name/cache`. Now I am sure that it is caching the data, because I tried to `Clear Cache` from `App info`, and it worked.

Comment: @DeepakBala No I am not, I am using the same code as above in the question. I just call `String response = getResponse(url)`.

Comment: How are you verifying that the data on the server changed? Is there a proxy between your client application and the server?

Comment: @DeepakBala Well I am changing the data only to test the application, and as I said before it did work when I tried to `Clear Cache` from `App info`, so the data is changing on the server.

Comment: I found the solution. I just had to add `httpconn.setUseCaches(false)` just after opening the connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see if the cache option is activated by default using:

```
getDefaultUseCaches(); //or
getUseCaches();
```

As seen [here in the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getDefaultUseCaches())

If you find there your problem, then you can simply change it using

```
setDefaultUseCaches(boolean newValue) //or
setUseCaches(boolean newValue) // Uses a flag (see documentation)
```

As seen [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDefaultUseCaches(boolean))